# SQL Query Fails for some records

Tags: sql, oracle, ms-access, varchar2, regexp-like

I'm running a query where I'm selecting records that contain a word in a **VarChar2(4000)** field. The query works but only for some dates and not others.

I've tried REGEXP_LIKE and INSTR. I've tried it in SQL Developer and ACCESS and I get the same results.

Oracle:

```
REGEXP_LIKE(Table, 'Text') 
INSTR(Table,'Text', 1)<>0
```

Access:

```
(((Table) Like "*" & "Text" & "*"));
```

Case sensitivity is not the issue.

Has anyone else seen an case like this before?

**Edited to show sample data:**

```
**Job    Date        Description**
1       6/6/2017      Blah Blah Text Blah      Query works and finds Text
2       6/6/2018      Blah Blah Text Blah      Query can't find Text
```

The same query works for any date prior to 2018.

Comment: Sample data and expected result will go a long way

Comment: When using the Oracle `REGEXP_LIKE()` function the second parameter should be a valid regular expression. In this case something like `'.*Text.*'`.

Comment: @TheImpaler . . . `'Text'` *is* a valid regular expression.  It will match "Text" anywhere in the column.

Comment: Does the following Access query return only the first of those 2 sample rows? `SELECT * FROM YourTableNameHere WHERE [Description] ALike '%Text%'`

Comment: @GordonLinoff I thought he wanted to search for a "word": that is, that specific sequence of letters surrounded by blank delimiters. My example was too simplistic. My bad.

Comment: Both ACCESS and Oracle provide the same results. The query works but only for records with a date before 2018.

Comment: Can you also show your actual **query**? What does the date column even have to do with your problem at all? Meaning - it is much more likely that you are doing something *else* in the query that causes whatever you think is wrong with the output.